# Mechanism: Instantaneously vary frequency of photons emitted, or passing, by, over a wide range of frequencies, with reliable consistent precision?

Tags: optics, photons, geometric-optics, quantum-optics, non-linear-optics

For an optical computing application, I need to set frequency of photons emitted or passing by a small mechanism, instantaneously, and it needs to be able to change this frequency from one instance to the next over a wide range of frequencies, with reliable consistent precision.

All the mechanisms I know of take too much time, as most are mechanical.  For instance, straining a crystal.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: This is a community Bot?  It already asks about small mechanisms that do one of two particular things.  The mechanisms people suggest, would answer the how.

Comment: That was indeed a bot comment, but your question probably would benefit a great deal from some further elaboration.  For one thing, it's not clear what you mean by, "set frequency of photons emitted or passing by a small mechanism," even qualitatively; the intended meaning of "set" there is not obvious.  Moreover, you mention a lot of technical requirements, such as "instantaneously" (nothing can truly be instantaneous), "wide range of frequencies," and "reliable consistent precision," for which it probably makes a big different what your quantitative goals actually are.

Comment: They don't give room for elaboration.  I'm looking for mechanisms that produce this effect within the generalised performance parameters.  In life, things only get as good as they get, so I am only asking which are the best ones, so I can assess wherever they would be a suitable mechanism.

Comment: "set frequency of photons emitted or passing by a small mechanism," even qualitatively; the intended meaning of "set" there is not obvious."

Set the frequency or change the frequency of photons as they pass by a small mechanism, or alternatively are emitted by (I should say included through mechanism as well) a small mechanism.   Wherever they are emitted or pass by/through, they produce the same result a stream of photons where the frequency can be controlled to a fine grain of time.

Comment: "Moreover,... "instantaneously" ..., "wide range of frequencies," and "reliable consistent precision," for which it probably makes a big different what your quantitative goals actually are".

A mechanism that does this instantaneously (i.e. single step and not mechanical, as quick as the photons come through it, able to vary from photon/photon group to photon/photon group, preferably with no intermittent frequencies between the two desired frequencies.  Speaks of the speed of changing the mechanism rather than the size, or length of the group).

Comment: That can do this over a large range of frequencies (number of).  Reliable consistent precision are other performance metrics.  Little noise and good precision consistently.  On a photonic level, that would be closer to 1nm or less in frequency, timing of change (including response) is preferred at over 1Thz, but 1Ghz is useful, and even at least 32khz+ has uses.

Comment: So, there are a range of possible low depth performances where it might still be useful, but the faster the better.  An instantaneous change allows for maximum performance.  Of course, on top of this, I will have to arrange a way to quickly trigger the mechanism circuit myself.  Hence it's a general question on quickest mechanisms, where I sort everything else out afterwards.

All over details I'm working on are TS.

Comment: Moderators, the posts are in reply to a request for details on a deep question.  Most things in depth, are a complicated set of simple things.

Comment: I agree with Buzz. Even after your stream of comments, it seems that you are in a better position to answer your question than even people proficient in photonics. You show that you have a background, but want an answer that suits your problem, by asking a question with a much larger scope.I still find your question immensely vague when inserted into the photonics industry. Its full of buzzwords and its incredibly large in scope. All I can recommend is for you to look into nonlinear optics, ultrafast optics, plasmonics.

Comment: And I second @Buzz's comment on "what your quantitative goals are". For example, which wavelengths should the whole thing use? Telecom? Vis? NIR? THz? Microwaves? CW or Pulsed? How much of a shift at your target wavelength? etc. A lot of things need to be better defined **in the question** itself